# Reactively handle errors in Discord4J without error propagation

Tags: java, reactive-programming, reactor, discord4j

I am making a discord bot in Discord4J, with a command handler that returns the valid command:

```java
return Mono.just(event.getCommandName())
        .filter(commandRegistry::has)
        .map(commandRegistry::get)
        .flatMap(discordCommand -> {
            try {
                return discordCommand.executeCommand(event);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
                return event.reply("Error occurred!").then();
            }
        })
        .then();
```

(discordCommand.executeCommand returns Mono)

If I try to handle the error with `doOnError` the error propagates and crashes the program. My question is, how do I make this reactive without the error propagating. Surrounding the entire block with try/catch doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `.doOnX` methods are what we call "side effects". They don't subscribe to anything, instead they are called whenever the condition is met.

So instead of using try/catch, for reactive we can do the following:

```java
return Mono.just(event.getCommandName())
    .filter(commandRegistry::has)
    .map(commandRegistry::get)
    .flatMap(discordCommand ->> discordCommand.executeCommand(event);})
    .doOnError(e -> logger.error("an error happened", e))
    .onErrorResume(e -> event.reply("Sorry, an error occurred"));
```

In the above, we use `.doOnError` as a side effect to log the error since there is no further reactive actions we wish to take when logging. Then, we use `onErrorResume` which allows us to gracefully handle the error by sending the user a reply instead of the error propagating.

Comment: Thank you! This just taught me how side effects / handling works!

Answer (score 1):

You can use onErrorResume to convert the error into "nothing" (Mono.empty()):

```
.onErrorResume(throwable -> {
    //Do whatever you want with the error
    return Mono.empty();
})
```